# all complex solutions of $z\sin(z)=1$?

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, roots, transcendental-equations

A possibly easy question,

Can we find all complex solutions of $z\sin(z)=1$ ?

My try:

Let $$\sin(z) = \frac{e^{iz} - e^{-iz}}{2i}$$
so we have 
$$
z\frac{e^{iz} - e^{-iz}}{2i}=1
$$

Not sure how can I continue ?

Thanks

EDIT : I have posted a related question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/859274/solution-of-expz-z-in-bbbc).

Comment: I don't think there is a nice closed form for the real solutions, let alone the complex ones.  But I may be wrong.

Comment: Lambert $W$ functions? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function

Comment: Numerically it appears that all roots of $z \sin z = 1$ are real.

Comment: @AntonioVargas You are right. You can prove this using  Rouche's Theorem.

Comment: @Krokop, if you post an answer proving that I'll also post an answer showing an approximation for the roots :)

Comment: @AntonioVargas My solution is pretty the same as Yiorgos here : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/709617/show-that-z-sinz-1-has-only-real-solutions?rq=1 :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As shown [elsewhere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/709617), $z\sin z=1$, with $z\in$ **C**, has only real solutions. So we are ultimately left with solving $x\sin x=1$, with $x\in$ **R**, which, unlike the solution to your [other](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/859274) question, does not possess a closed form, not even in terms of the special [Lambert *W* function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). However, what we can say for certain, is that it has exactly two solutions in each interval of the form $\Big[2n\pi,(2n+1)\pi\Big]$ for $n\ge0$ and $\Big[(2k-1)\pi,2k\pi\Big]$ for $k\le0$, whose values get closer to the two extremities of the interval as *x* increases in absolute value. The only way to compute them is by using [numerical methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_analysis), such as [Newton's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method), for instance. Here are the first few, with a precision of $45$ decimals:

$$\pm1.11415714087193008730052517816920390395410138$$
$$\pm2.77260470826599123395356972149927927932229123$$

$$\pm6.43911723841724646172451484031087947865696505$$
$$\pm9.31724294141480961860128851356951156244980218$$

Answer (score 2):

See the following paper:

Charles Edward Siewert and Ernest Edmund Burniston, *Exact analytical solutions of* $ze^{z} = a,$ **Journal of Mathematical Analysis and Applications** 43 #3 (September 1973), 626-632.

> **Author's Abstract:** By means of the theory of complex variables, the solutions of $ze^{z} = a,$ where $a$ is in general complex, are established analytically, and thereby reduced to elementary quadratures.

Comment: The journal is well known and in most university libraries, at least in the U.S. I don't have access to a digital copy, however. My copy is a photocopy I once got from a university library. It's at home, so I don't have access to it now. The information I posted about it is from a personal bibliography of mine, within which I found this paper by simply searching for "transcendental equation". This is a phrase I made sure to include in my information about the item so that if I ever needed to search for something like this (as I just did), it would turn up.

Comment: A downloadable version:

http://www4.ncsu.edu/~ces/pdfversions/62.pdf

Answer (score 0):

If we look at $\frac{\sin x}{x}=0$, we can factor 
\begin{equation} \frac{\sin x}{x}=\left(1-\frac{x}{\pi}\right)\left(1+\frac{x}{\pi}\right)\left(1-\frac{x}{2\pi}\right)\left(1+\frac{x}{2\pi}\right)\ldots =\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{x}{k\pi}\right)\left(1+\frac{x}{k\pi}\right)\end{equation}
What about 
$$x\sin x=x^2\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{x^2}{(k\pi)^2}\right)=1$$
$$2\ln x + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\ln \left(1-\frac{x^2}{(n\pi)^2}\right)=0$$
Maybe it helps somehow.

Answer (score 0):

With [Lagrange reversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_reversion_theorem):

$$x\sin(x)=1\iff x=\{2\pi k+\csc^{-1}(x),(2k+1)\pi-\csc^{-1}(x)\}$$

Therefore:

$$x_{2k}=2k\pi+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n!} \left.\frac{d^{n-1}}{dw^{n-1}}\csc^{-1}(w)^n\right|_{2k\pi}
\\x_{2k+1}=(2k+1)\pi+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\left.\frac{d^{n-1}}{dw^{n-1}}\csc^{-1}(w)^n\right|_{(2k+1)\pi}$$

with examples [shown](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=lim%5B+3.0+pi+%2Bsum%5B%28-1%29%5En%2Fn%21+D%5B%28acsc%28w%29%29%5En%2C%7Bw%2Cn-1%7D%5D%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C5%7D%5D%2Cw-%3E3+*pi%5D) [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=x+sin%28x%29%2Cx%3D4+pi+%2Bsum%5B1%2Fn%21+D%5B%28acsc%28w%29%29%5En%2C%7Bw%2Cn-1%7D%5D%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C5%7D%5D%2Cw%3D4.0+pi+). The next step could be [expanding $\ln^n(x)$](https://functions.wolfram.com/IntegerFunctions/StirlingS1/23/02/0001/)

Comment: “shown here” example matching Lucian’s results. Derivatives to be evaluated