# Solution of $\exp(z)=z$ in $\Bbb{C}$.

Tags: complex-analysis, numerical-methods, roots, transcendental-equations

I have posted a related question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/858924/all-complex-solutions-of-z-sinz-1). I thinkg this one is more interesting:

> What about the solution of $\exp(z)=z$ in $\Bbb{C}$?

My try :

$z \mapsto e^z - z$ is entire non-constant.

Perhaps $z \mapsto e^z - z$ can be developed in Weierstrass product.

Also any numerically approach will be very interesting.

Thanks you in advance.

Comment: [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217254/apparently-cannot-be-solved-using-logarithms/217262#217262) a more general case.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal Nice, +1 for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If

$$z = e^z$$

then

$$-ze^{-z} = -1$$

so

$$-z = W(-1)$$

and thus

$$z = - W(-1),$$

where $W$ is any branch of the [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Comment: Thanks, wikipedia said :$W\left(-1\right) \approx -0.31813-1.33723{\rm{i}}$, did you know how can we prove this ?

Comment: Use Newton's method on the equation $z=e^z$ with an initial guess like $0.3+1.3i$.

Comment: Newton's method, did you mean that  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method ? I am unfamiliar with it if you can expand your answer (if you have time ).

Comment: Yes, that's the right wiki page.  Newton's method is an iterative process for finding numerical approximations to solutions of equations.  I definitely recommend reading about it - any calculus book should have a good description of the process.

Comment: Thanks! I will read about it so. (BTW +1 even if is a community wiki)